# jQuery selector can't find my <select> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('select').each(function(sel)
  {
    // TODO: I am going to execute some logic here. But it never happens because jQuery can't find the select tags.
    alert(sel);
  });
  alert($('select').length); // why does this return zero? there are select tags on the page!
</script>
<select>
    <option value='' selected='true'></option>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='25'>.25</option>
    <option value='50'>.5</option>
    <option value='75'>.75</option>
    <option value='100'>1</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value='' selected='true'></option>
    <option value='1'>A</option>
    <option value='2'>B</option>
    <option value='3'>C</option>
    <option value='4'>D</option>
    <option value='5'>E</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do something with the `<select>` tags that are on this page (on my actual page there are maybe a dozen of them, but in this example I'll just show two). However I can't select them using jQuery because the `$('select')` selector returns an empty list. Why is jQuery not finding my `<select>` tags? How else can I enumerate them?

Comment: You're running your jQuery before the element exists. Move it to the end of the body or put it within a document ready hanlder

Comment: Have you tried giving the select id tag example: 

<select id="select1">
    <option value='' selected='true'></option>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='25'>.25</option>
    <option value='50'>.5</option>
    <option value='75'>.75</option>
    <option value='100'>1</option>
</select>

alert($('#select1').length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').each(function(sel) {
    alert(sel);
  });
  alert($('select').length); 
});
```

Or put the script at the end of document.

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks! I always forget that JavaScript executes inline with the HTML; I keep thinking of HTML as a canvas that is fully drawn before the JavaScript executes, but that's not true...

Answer (score 1):

By the time the `script` is running the `select` tags has not yet been created, so they won't be found. You can move the `script` to the bottom of the body to make sure all the elements in the body has already been rendered before trying to select them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select>
    <option value='' selected='true'></option>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='25'>.25</option>
    <option value='50'>.5</option>
    <option value='75'>.75</option>
    <option value='100'>1</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value='' selected='true'></option>
    <option value='1'>A</option>
    <option value='2'>B</option>
    <option value='3'>C</option>
    <option value='4'>D</option>
    <option value='5'>E</option>
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('select').each(function(sel)
  {
    // TODO: I am going to execute some logic here. But it never happens because jQuery can't find the select tags.
    alert(sel);
  });
  alert($('select').length); // why does this return zero? there are select tags on the page!
</script>
</body>
</html>
```